I try to run genetic algorithm for optimize hyperparameters of ANN keras model. But I encounter many errors
I am trying to optimize my ANN model using Genetic Algorithm. The code I wrote is:
# Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
def create_model():
 # create model
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Dense( 6,  input_shape = (29,) , activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))
 model.add(Dense( 6, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))
 model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))
# Compile model
 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
 return model

# create model
model = KerasClassifier(model=create_model, verbose=0)

param_grid = {'activation': ["logistic", "relu", "Tanh"],
              'hidden_layer_sizes': [(50,),(100,), (50,70), (100,70), (100,100)],
              'learning_rate': ['constant','invscaling','adaptive'],
              }

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True)

evolved_estimator = GASearchCV(estimator=model,
                               cv=cv,
                               scoring='accuracy',
                               population_size=10,
                               generations=35,
                               tournament_size=3,
                               elitism=True,
                               crossover_probability=0.8,
                               mutation_probability=0.1,
                               param_grid=param_grid,
                               criteria='max',
                               algorithm='eaMuPlusLambda',
                               n_jobs=-1,
                               verbose=True,
                               keep_top_k=4)

but when run it, this will showed:
ValueError: activation must be a valid instance of Integer, Categorical or Continuous classes
I tried to fix this error.
After searching, I found out that it can be written like this(Although I had to change hidden_layer_sizes parameter):
param_grid = {'activation': Categorical(["logistic", "relu", "Tanh"]),
              'hidden_layer_sizes': Integer(50,100),
              'learning_rate': Categorical(['constant','invscaling','adaptive']),
              }

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True)

evolved_estimator = GASearchCV(estimator=model,
                               cv=cv,
                               scoring='accuracy',
                               population_size=10,
                               generations=35,
                               tournament_size=3,
                               elitism=True,
                               crossover_probability=0.8,
                               mutation_probability=0.1,
                               param_grid=param_grid,
                               criteria='max',
                               algorithm='eaMuPlusLambda',
                               n_jobs=-1,
                               verbose=True,
                               keep_top_k=4)

This part of the code was executed. But when I tried to fit the optimized model on the training data, it gave me this error:
GA_result = evolved_estimator.fit(x_train, y_train)

ValueError: Invalid parameter activation for estimator KerasClassifier. This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasClassifier constructor: KerasClassifier(activation=Tanh) Check the list of available parameters with estimator.get_params().keys()
I am really confused. Can anyone help me?
